# callback not working in codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback, codeigniter-form-helper

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword', 'Password', 'required|matches[password]', 'callback__matcherror');



        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('login');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->load->view('insert_dream');

        }

    }

public function _matcherror() {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_matcherror', 'Passwords should match');
    return FALSE;
}

}
?>
```

i am a newbie to codeigniter. The above code doesnt display passwords should match error message. Is something wrong with the callback or Am i missing something.

Comment: I think you need to load `form_validation` library in your call back function  put `$this->load->library('form_validation');` in `_matcherror` and see the result

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Why your _matcherror function return FALSE??

Comment: If all you are doing is changing the message - you don't need to do that in a callback function. Just put it in with the rest of your form setup code.

Comment: removed return FALSE.. still isnt working

Comment: $this->load->library('form_validation'); added isnt working .. the same result it shows The Password field is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form#cascading-rules). You don't need to make a callback.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `callback__matcherror` as fourth parameter of `set_rules` function.It should be 3rd parameter. Use this way

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword', 'Password', 'required|matches[password]|callback__matcherror');
```

**Note**

You will get this error message if your password fields match.Because you applying 3 rule there.3rd rule(call_back_function) will apply when 2nd rule is success. Your 2nd rule will valid when passwords matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
matches[password]
```

will automatically check for password. You need not to use callback function `callback__matcherror`